# Function Overloading and returning different data types depending on the same input

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I am still new to C++, and I know this project I'm working on shouldn't be programmed in C++ because of the intricacy, but I thought it would be a great way to learn some of the ins-and-outs of C++. I have a storage vector of base class pointers that are pointers to multiple different derived class objects. However, I would like to find the easiest way to cast the base class pointer in a way to use the derived class member functions (technically they are sliced off, but I am using the "new" keyword when pushing back the vector with a derived class object). I have talked with other computer science colleagues, and they have said this is the best way to do what I want to do (inheritance and polymorphism). I have a couple variables in the Base class that determines which type of derive class the pointer is pointing to, so I have no trouble figuring out what is what, but is it possible to find a way to cast these base class pointers as their own derived class permanently? Or at least make a function to quickly cast each pointer (B2D)? I was told I might be able to use function overloading. Here is an example of what I think would happen (but is probably horribly wrong)

```cpp
class base{

public:
std::string getdTypeName; // getter function for the variable
private:
std::string dTypeName;

}

class d1 : public base{

public:
//functions exclusive to d1
dTypeName=derived1;

}

class d2 : public base{

public:
//functions exclusive to d2
dTypeName=derived2;

}

class d3 : public base{

public:
//functions exclusive to d3
dTypeName=derived3;
}

std::vector<base*> storage; // these are randomly generated but for now this will do
storage.push_back(new d1);
storage.push_back(new d2);
storage.push_back(new d3);

if(storage[0]->getdTypeName()=="derived1"){
//static or dynamic cast as d1 object, or pointer? or something else?
}

if(storage[0]->getdTypeName()=="derived2"){
//same as above but with d2 object/pointer
}

if(storage[0]->getdTypeName()=="derived3"{
//same as above with d3 object/pointer
// do the above with each index?
}
```

Knowing the scope of what I'm trying to program, I don't think it would matter too much if I had to check every index as many times as there are derived classes, but is there a more efficient way to do a B2D cast? And would I have to do this method every time I wanted to do the B2D cast? If so, is it possible to condense it to a function? I was trying to think through this, and one of the problems I ran into is the return type, since whatever the dTypeName is determines the data type. Would I need to overload it three times but return different data types depending on the result of the if-statements? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you need to down cast at all? use polymorphous with `virtual` methods.

Comment: and please [learn how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" and "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!"

Answer (score 0):

What you want could be achieved using virtual functions.

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void doSomething()
  {
    // base implementation
  }
};

class D1 : public Base
{
public:

  void doSomething() override
  {
    // D1 implmentation
  }
};

class D2 : public Base
{
public:

  void doSomething() override
  {
    // D2 implmentation
  }
};
```

in main() now you can call doSomething on base pointers without worrying about their type.

If you would still like to do casting as a learning exercise, you can use dynamic_cast which would return nullptr if the type doesn't match with the actual stored pointer.

Answer (score 0):

With your method, you might use `dynamic_cast`

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = default;
};

struct d1 : base {};
struct d2 : base {};
struct d3 : base {};

void foo(base& b)
{
    if (auto* d = dynamic_cast<d1*>(&b)) {
         std::cout << "derived 1\n";
    } else if (auto* d = dynamic_cast<d2*>(&b)) {
         std::cout << "derived 2\n";
    } else if (auto* d = dynamic_cast<d3*>(&b)) {
         std::cout << "derived 3\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    d1 o1;
    d2 o2;
    d3 o3;
    std::vector<base*> bases{&o1, &o2, &o3};

    for (auto* b : bases) {
        foo(*b);
    }
}
```

But better to use virtual method:

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct d1 : base { void foo() override { std::cout << "derived 1\n";} };
struct d2 : base { void foo() override { std::cout << "derived 2\n";} };
struct d3 : base { void foo() override { std::cout << "derived 3\n";} };

int main()
{
    d1 o1;
    d2 o2;
    d3 o3;
    std::vector<base*> bases{&o1, &o2, &o3};

    for (auto* b : bases) {
        b->foo();
    }
}
```